# Android and SQLite

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use existing database with Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-existing-database-with-android-app)

A buddy and I are trying to figure this problem out.  He created a database in SQLite and we are trying to figure out how to basically get that database into a android app we created without having to create one from scratch within eclipse.  I watched tutorial videos on how to create a DB from scratch but since he already made one how would it be possible to import it?  Also anyone know of any good tutorials on SQLite + eclipse?  Thanks :)

Comment: This is what you are looking for
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-existing-database-with-android-app/9109728#9109728

Comment: [link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)this is good link for sqlitedatabase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one out. It worked for me. =]

The only thing it doesn't tell you is if you alter the database you provided with the app, you have to either rename it or delete it and reinsert it into your assets folder.

Not sure why that is, but if you don't do that it'll keep reading the old database and not the updated one.

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

If you  have to update your app on Google Play, follow the instructions in this link: http://support.andromo.com/kb/distributing/how-to-update-your-app-in-google-play